# Can I teach GHC mathematical induction?

Tags: haskell, tuples, data-kinds

I attempted to create a datatype representing a tuple of infinitely many types:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
{-# LANGUAGE QuantifiedConstraints #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}

import GHC.TypeNats

infixr 5 :!!

data OmegaTuple (t :: Nat -> *) (n :: Nat) = t n :!! OmegaTuple t (n+1)
```

This is fine.

I also attempted to declare the direct product of infinitely many semigroups:

```
instance (Semigroup (t n), Semigroup (OmegaTuple t (n+1))) => Semigroup (OmegaTuple t n) where
    (x :!! xs) <> (y :!! ys) = x <> y :!! xs <> ys
```

Yet GHC complains like this:

```
• Illegal nested constraint ‘Semigroup (OmegaTuple t (n + 1))’
  (Use UndecidableInstances to permit this)
```

If I understood correctly, using `UndecidableInstances` will make GHC fall in an infinite loop.

Another attempt:

```
instance (Semigroup (t n), forall k. Semigroup (t k) => Semigroup (t (k+1))) => Semigroup (OmegaTuple t n) where
    (x :!! xs) <> (y :!! ys) = x <> y :!! xs <> ys
```

Then GHC complains like this:

```
• Illegal type synonym family application ‘k + 1’ in instance:
    Semigroup (t (k + 1))
```

Is it really impossible to teach GHC mathematical induction?

Comment: The built-in `Nat` is almost useless without compiler plugins. Try doing everything in terms of `data Nat = Z | S Nat` instead and your life will be better.

Comment: Turnng on `UndecidableInstances` won't always make GHC loop. What it does is disable some conditions GHC normally requires. Those conditions are designed to guarantee that constraint checking will terminate, but the absence of those conditions doesn't guarantee that it **won't** terminate; the class of programs that can be easily checked in advance for termination is smaller than the class of programs that actually do terminate. And I believe GHC actually has a finite depth for constraint resolution anyway, so it'll still barf if you mess up. It's a safe extension.

Comment: @Ben Still, in this case, any use site of the given `Semigroup` instance would indeed infinitely loop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can manually wrap the dictionaries, that allows lazily building up an “infinite class dictionary”:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs     #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
 
import Data.Kind (Type)
import GHC.TypeLits

data SemigroupSequence (t :: Nat -> Type) (n :: Nat) where
  SemigroupSequence :: Semigroup (t n)
     => SemigroupSequence t (n+1) -> SemigroupSequence t n

class SemigroupFamily t where
  semigroupSequence :: SemigroupSequence t 0
```

and then

```
mappendOmega :: SemigroupSequence t n
     -> OmegaTuple t n -> OmegaTuple t n -> OmegaTuple t n
mappendOmega (SemigroupSequence sd') (x :!! xs) (y :!! ys)
   = x <> y :!! mappendOmega sd' xs ys

instance (SemigroupFamily t) => Semigroup (OmegaTuple t 0) where
  (<>) = mappendOmega semigroupSequence
```

Comment: You might also write `SemigroupSequence` in terms of `OmegaTuple` as `data SemigroupIndexed (t :: k -> Type) (n :: k) where SemigroupIndexed :: Semigroup (t n) => SemigroupIndexed t n` and `type SemigroupSequence t = OmegaTuple (SemigroupIndexed t)`. This too generalizes to expressing that a constraint holds for an infinite sequence of types.